# How do I enter strikethrough text in a web form

Tags: html, formatting, webforms

Is it possible to submit some text in web form where some of the text is in <strike>strikethough?</strike>

Is there some Alt key combination that I can use?

Comment: could you give us some background as to why you want to, this might help us answer. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can enter strikethrough text into a web-form using unicode characters, which is pretty universal these days.  To generate the text, you could use one of these tools and then copy/paste the output.

http://adamvarga.com/strike/

Answer (score 1):

Strikethrough is like a font. It's an attribute of the text, not text itself. Since forms are submitted in plain text, you can't have any formatting submitted with it.

Comment: Richard: From this very page, the above strike-through effect was achieved by the following html code : "<strike>strikethough?</strike>". Evidently, you can't enter anything like that in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it supports HTML, no, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but it depends on the web form. Most web forms accept just plain text.

You see strikethrough on web pages (like in your question) as a bit of HTML formatting. If the web form supports HTML it *might* support strikethrough. Try using the `<strike>` tag around your text.

There is also a [combining diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_diacritic) defined for overlaying strikethrough on Unicode characters, but that's even more esoteric than HTML support in a web form.

Comment: hmm...lets try the diacritic. how's this look: 
̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶

Comment: That's pretty cool, comes out on my screen OK. I got it just by copy & pasting the character from the wikipedia unicode page inbetween each letter. If your web form supports unicode, like superuser seems to, then it should work.

Comment: Here's another test: u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲

Comment: why is it esoteric? just because your languages does not use diacritics often, they are not an esoteric thing…

Comment: Fair point. My apologies